# working with spectra (energy/ data paires)

Tags: python, data-science, physics, resampling, spectrum

I am going to subtract two spectra
1- Experimental result (Energy, data),
2- Simulated results (Energy, data)
to observed the error using python.

As the first step I need to have a **same number of data point**, **normalized both to one** and **shift the simulated results to match the max peak of both simulated and experimental results**. till now everything is OK.
But for subtracting two, they will be subtracted with respect to index while I need to subtract the data with the same energy, therefore the result wont be correct!!!

As an example it would be a simple illustration of the problem:
[here is the dummy sample of the data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdtGg.png)

Any suggestion to how subtract the data with the same energy!?!

it is the part of code which I used for normalization and shift of the spectra.
the last line is also the subtraction line.

```
for x in R:
   maxnorXAS=x.XASSUM.max()
   mxindXAS=(x.XASSUM==maxnorXAS).idxmax()#list(x[x==maxnor].index)
   ESHXAS=mxEnXAS-x.Energy[mxindXAS]
   x.XASSUM=x.XASSUM/maxnorXAS
   x.Energy+=ESHXAS
   x['XASDIFF']=x.XASSUM-Exp[0].XASSUM
```

[plotted data with respect to the index and their difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01LNr.png)

[plotted data with respect to the energy, but their difference will be wrong as the "-" operator is acts on cells with the same index.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hyzd.png)

**I think I can summarize the problem as interpolation (resampling the energy column with respect to experimental result) of the shifted simulated data to experimental Energy set.**

Comment: What are the data types of `x` and `mxEnXAS`?

Comment: all the data are float. each x is a list of Energy, Data1. and mxEnXAS is the energy for the max of the experimental data. (experimental peak position) this line is to find the necessary shift. the image which I attached can clarified the problem I think.

Comment: in fact each x gives you a set of simulated data (right side of the image)

Comment: I've added two image which shows the problem with index and Energy! in Fig.2 there are two plots with 1000 data points which are plotted together. therefore you can see the shift. Fig.3 shows the same plot, but this time with respect to the energy. (the shift is clear from both side of the green and blue plots)

Comment: yes, in fact by replacing normal index with Energy and re indexing now I have two sets of spectra with the exact sampling on x axis.